# How to optimize binary search of a vector?

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, vector

I am trying to implement a find method on a sorted vector of key value pairs. Right now it is performing slower than map.find(key). Theoretically it should be faster because the vector can take better advantage of CPU caching because of its contiguous memory. I'm just wondering if there is anything obviously wrong with this implementation and if there is any way I can optimize it? I don't think using a standard algorithm is an option here, because the closest possible option is lower_bound and that will incur the extra overhead of the checks I will have to perform to verify whether or not it found anything. Beyond that, lower_bound would require me to construct a pair (plus the wrapper I put around it) to give it as the value I'm searching for, incurring even more unnecessary overhead.

```
FlatMap<KEY, VALUE, COMPARATOR>::findImp(const key_type &key)
{
    typename VectorType::iterator lower = d_elements.begin();
    typename VectorType::iterator upper = d_elements.end();
    typename VectorType::iterator middle;
    while(lower < upper) {
        middle = lower + (upper-lower)/2;
        if(d_comparator(middle->data().first, key)){
            lower = middle;
            ++lower;
        } else if(d_comparator(key, middle->data().first)){
            upper = middle;
        } else {
            return middle;
        }
    }
    return d_elements.end();
}
```

Note that `d_elements` is a vector of pairs (the pairs are in a wrapper):

```
vector<FlatMap_Element<KEY, VALUE> >  d_elements;
```

The wrapper itself just holds the pair as a data member and does some magic with assignment that shouldn't affect search:

```
template <class KEY, class VALUE>
class FlatMap_Element {
    bsl::pair<const KEY, VALUE> d_data;
    ...
    pair<const KEY, VALUE>& data();
    pair<const KEY, VALUE> const& data() const;
};
```

I know that the business with the wrapper is **not** the source of the slowdown, beaucse I have tested this algorithm on a vector or pairs without the wrapper and had the same performance.

Any suggestions for tweaks are appreciated.

Comment: One obvious improvement would be to use d_comparator only once. In theory, you call some function that given two values returns -1, 0 or 1, and reassign your bounds with that information. Apparently your comparator works differently because it returns `true` if one param is more than another, and `false` otherwise. I would consider switching to a comparator that can be called only once and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I don't follow on why `std::lower_bound` isn't an option?  Have you tried it?  It may already be faster even with "the checks" (?) you have to add.

Comment: You reject `std::lower_bound` for its final test of equality whereas your version does the check at each iteration...

Comment: @Ashalynd That is the option I prefer, however this is a part of a data structure that is supposed to be a drop in replacement for std::map, so I have to accept a comparator that just does a less than comparison.

Comment: @Jarod42 Lower bound does this exact same kind of check every iteration as well. Calling lower bound requires me to double check whether the value returned is pointing to the value I want or some other value that was close because the value I wanted was not found. The problem is lower_bound is for a slightly different use case than this, meaning that even though it has the information I need (value found or not) it does not easily convey it back to me, forcing an extra check after I call lower_bound.

Comment: use `middle = (lower+upper)/2;` instead of `middle = lower + (upper-lower)/2;` maybe it would reduce the arithmetic a little.

Comment: @Sachamora I had this idea as well, except `(lower+upper)/2` isn't possible since I dont believe random access iterators support iterator addition nor division by an int http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/

Comment: Since C++11, you can use [std::partition_point](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_point) instead of [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound). The former does not require you to pass a pair.

Comment: @nosid That's really handy, unfortunately I'm stuck with C++03 right now.

Comment: @GBleaney stick with your mid-calc. `middle = (lower+upper)/2;` is susceptible to overflow for sufficiently large `upper` and `lower`. You're doing it right in calculating the difference and adding to `lower`. Were I to change that at all it would be `middle = std::next(lower, std::distance(lower, upper)/2);`

Comment: @GBleaney: `std::lower_bound` use result of `comp` only once by loop whereas you use it a second time to see if you update upper bound or return.

Comment: @GBleaney, if you could share the complete sample benchmark it would be easier to verify your assumptions and look for possible improvements...

Comment: "Lower bound does this exact same kind of check every iteration". If you have verified that by looking at the source, [consider switching to an implementation that does it right](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/stl__algo_8h-source.html#l02610).

Comment: @n.m. Thanks, I will try to follow that implementation.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ok, I see what you're saying. I'll trying switching to a lower_bound style implementation and then the extra checks at the end.

Comment: Don't follow it, call it.

Comment: Are you sure lower_bound is too slow? Did you benchmark optimized code?

Comment: Try with creating a look-up-table. This [link](http://geidav.wordpress.com/2013/12/29/optimizing-binary-search/) may help you.

Comment: Don't assume lower_bound is too slow without benchmarking. In fact, don't assume anything without benchmarking / profiling. Any time you start guessing about performance there's a pretty high chance you're going to be wrong.

Comment: @n.m. As I mentioned above "lower_bound would require me to construct a pair (plus the wrapper I put around it) to give it as the value I'm searching for, incurring even more unnecessary overhead." I think it is wiser to use the same algorithm, but not call that directly.

Comment: @GBleaney: You have to create a pair **or** provide a *compare functor*.

Comment: @Jarod42 No, you have to do just a pair or a pair **and** a compare functor. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/?kw=lower_bound

Comment: @GBleaney: No, `T` and "`decltype(*first)`" may be different https://ideone.com/snZTRu

Comment: @Jarod42 Is that true for C++03 as well?

Comment: @GBleaney: Yes, you have to create your class functor instead of the lambda.

Comment: @Jarod42 do you want to turn that into an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version use twice `m_comparator` result by loop whereas `std::lower_bound` use only one comparaison.

So you may use something like: (C++03)

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename KeyComparator>
struct helper_comp
{
    bool operator (const std::pair<const Key, Value>& lhs, const Key& rhs) const {
        return comp(lhs.first, rhs);
    }
    KeyComparator comp;
};

template <typename Key, typename Value, typename KeyComparator>
typename std::vector<std::pair<const Key, Value>>::const_iterator
my_find(const std::vector<std::pair<const Key, Value>>& v, const Key& key)
{
    auto it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), key, helper_comp<Key, Value, KeyComparator>());
    if (it != v.end() && it->first == key) {
        return it;
    }
    return v.end();
}
```

or use lambda instead of external `struct helper_comp`(C++11) (https://ideone.com/snZTRu)

Comment: Wouldn't `helper_comp` need to be able to handle both conditions of pair/key and key/pair comparisons?

Comment: Not sure, I think msvc requires it in debug to check if container is sorted.

Comment: That would be a pair/pair comparison. I think to be safe you should provide all 3 then, even if your particular compiler implementation doesn't use all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would single-step it at the assembly language level.
Every instruction should be pulling its weight.
If it seems to be too complicated, then that's why it's a performance problem.

Keep in mind the binary search example given years ago by Jon Bentley.
If the table has 1024 entries it looks like this:

```
i = 0;
if (v >= a[i+512]) i += 512;
if (v >= a[i+256]) i += 256;
if (v >= a[i+128]) i += 128;
if (v >= a[i+ 64]) i +=  64;
if (v >= a[i+ 32]) i +=  32;
if (v >= a[i+ 16]) i +=  16;
if (v >= a[i+  8]) i +=   8;
if (v >= a[i+  4]) i +=   4;
if (v >= a[i+  2]) i +=   2;
if (v >= a[i+  1]) i +=   1;
```

Big-O isn't everything. This is still only O(log n), but it runs rings around the naive implementation.

Comment: Doesn't seem to run circles around much of anything when I try it.  Bear in mind that most of the time in a binary search is spent waiting for the data to get shipped back from memory, rather than having the CPU do something productive.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Did you single-step it at the assembly-language level, where it should come out to about 4-5 instructions per line? OK, with serious memory latency it could be slower.

Comment: Why are you talking about counting instructions here?  This trick generates a nice piece of code.  But that nice piece of code does not run significantly faster than the loopy version because the execution time is dominated by cache misses, not instruction execution.  (It's actually about three instructions per line.)

Comment: "Years ago" when instruction and memory speeds were more evenly matched this might have been worthwhile. Not terribly useful though, as you need a constant number of elements that's a power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

You might try a ternary or a quaternary search instead.  The first bunch of iterations are essentially doing random memory access.  That has considerable latency.  You can mostly-hide a few more random memory accesses in that latency and do fewer of them.

One potential pitfall here is that cache associativity might make higher-order searches whose stride is a power of two behave poorly.

I'd also add that your extra comparator call really doesn't help you very much.  You get lucky (find the thing you were looking for before the last iteration) less than half the time.  If you fix your binary search, you will only need to check it on the last iteration.